# Can I use an IBOutlet property throughout my code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iboutlet

I need to connect an IBOutlet from this UIImageView to my ViewController in order to perform animations on it (just swiping a stone-like block around a grid).

However, I already have a category file that has an (+instancetype) method to  create the UIImage programmatically, so I can use it to set an instance variable (usable throughout other files).  Problem is (and bear with me because I am new to performing animation methods on movable objects) I can't use that instance variable (which is a UIView*) to do any animations.  Actually, let me know if there is a way (to be used with the +(void)animateWithDuration.... method) because it would be beneficial.

```
    + (instancetype)stoneOneCreator {
         UIImage* stoneOneImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Stone.png"];
         UIImageView* stoneOneView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                             stoneOneImage];
         return stoneOneView;
    }
```

I call this method in my ViewController, set it to an IV, then use that IV throughout the other files where needed.

```
    @implementation
    {
        UIView* _one;
    }

    _one = [UIView stoneOneCreator];
```

Then use _one by passing into other methods that are implemented in other files etc. etc.

My outlet property though when I'm working with the storyboard is

```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* stoneOne;
```

Is there a way to use the 'stoneOne' property for IV purposes similar to '_one'?  Or, is there a way to tie together the '_one' IV with the 'stoneOne' property?

Thanks,

Anthony